# Haskell error: The type signature for 'xxx' lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: haskell

The error is: The type signature for `firtstWords' lacks an accompanying binding

Code is:

```
firtstWords :: IO ()
firstWords = hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering >> 
             putStrLn "Blah..."
```

If I erase the type signature, code is OK.

EDIT: OK ... It's spelling fail ... firts /= first

Comment: If you think your problem is solved, you "accept" it. That will close your question as "resolved".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake `first` and `firts`. 
That's why type checking is great ;-)

Comment: SH** ... stupid mistake ...

Comment: You misspelled the spelling mistake as well! There's no `firts`, only `firtst`.